# Interactive transition between view controllers

Tags: ios, comparative-review, animation, swift, controller

I have made an interactive transition controller in Swift in two different ways.

This interactive transition controller is the parent class and I have few child classes which adapt the parent for each situation where I need an interactive transition.

The first way, the parent doesn't use a delegate and forces the children to implement the methods by writing `fatalError("Must Override")` in the implementation of the methods in the parent.

Parent class:

```
private var presenting = false
weak var delegate: InteractiveControllerTransitionDelegate!

private var interactionController: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition?

var edge: UIRectEdge!

weak var fromViewController: UIViewController! {
didSet {
    let screenEdgePanRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "presentingViewController:")
    screenEdgePanRecognizer.edges = edge
    fromViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(screenEdgePanRecognizer)
}
}

weak var toViewController: UIViewController! {
didSet {
    let screenEdgePanRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissingViewController:")
    screenEdgePanRecognizer.edges = oppositeEdgeForEdge(edge)
    toViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(screenEdgePanRecognizer)
}
}

private let animationSynchronizationQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.nico.app.animationsynchronization", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
private var animationSynchronizationQueueSuspended = false

func dispatchToMainFromSynchronizationQueue(block: dispatch_block_t) {
    dispatch_async(animationSynchronizationQueue) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
    }
}


// MARK: - UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol methods

func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return 0.3
}

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    if animationSynchronizationQueueSuspended {
        dispatch_resume(animationSynchronizationQueue)
        animationSynchronizationQueueSuspended = false
    }

    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()
    let screens: (from: UIViewController, to: UIViewController) = (transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!, transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!)

    let parentViewController = presenting ? screens.from : screens.to
    let childViewController = presenting ? screens.to : screens.from

    let parentView = parentViewController.view
    let childView = childViewController.view

    // positionning the "to" viewController's view for the animation
    if presenting {
        offStageChildViewController(childView)
    }

    containerView.addSubview(parentView)    
    containerView.addSubview(childView)

    let duration = transitionDuration(transitionContext)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
        if self.presenting {
            self.onStageViewController(childView)
            self.offStageParentViewController(parentView)
        } else {
            self.onStageViewController(parentView)
            self.offStageChildViewController(childView)
        }}, completion: { finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
    })
}

// MARK: gesture handlers

// presenting
func presentingViewController(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let percentage = getPercentage(pan)

    switch pan.state {

    case .Began:
        dispatch_suspend(animationSynchronizationQueue)
        animationSynchronizationQueueSuspended = true
        interactionController = UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition()
        presentViewController(pan)

    case .Changed:
        dispatchToMainFromSynchronizationQueue() {
            self.interactionController?.updateInteractiveTransition(percentage)
        }

    case .Ended:
        let velocity = pan.velocityInView(self.toViewController.view)
        dispatchToMainFromSynchronizationQueue() {
            if self.finishPresenting(velocity, percentage: percentage) {
                self.interactionController?.finishInteractiveTransition()
            } else {
                self.interactionController?.cancelInteractiveTransition()
            }
            self.interactionController = nil
        }


    default:
        break
    }
}

// dismissing
func dismissingViewController(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let percentage = getPercentage(pan)

    switch pan.state {

    case .Began:
        dispatch_suspend(animationSynchronizationQueue)
        animationSynchronizationQueueSuspended = true
        interactionController = UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition()
        dismissViewController(pan)

    case .Changed:
        dispatchToMainFromSynchronizationQueue() {
            self.interactionController?.updateInteractiveTransition(percentage)
        }

    case .Ended:
        let velocity = pan.velocityInView(self.toViewController.view)
        dispatchToMainFromSynchronizationQueue() {
            if self.finishDismissing(velocity, percentage: percentage) {
                self.doOnCompletion()
                self.interactionController?.finishInteractiveTransition()
            } else {
                self.doOnCancellation()
                self.interactionController?.cancelInteractiveTransition()
            }
            self.interactionController = nil
        }

    default:
        break
    }
}


// MARK: Affine Transforming methods

// MARK: Mandatory methods
func getPercentage(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> CGFloat {
    fatalError("Must Override")
}

func onStageViewController(view: UIView) {
    fatalError("Must Override")
}

func offStageParentViewController(view: UIView) {
    fatalError("Must Override")
}

func offStageChildViewController(view: UIView) {
    fatalError("Must Override")
}

func presentViewController(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    fatalError("Must Override")
}

func dismissViewController(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    fatalError("Must Override")
}

// Optionnal methods
func doOnCompletion() {

}

func doOnCancellation() {

}

func finishPresenting(velocity: CGPoint, percentage: CGFloat) -> Bool {
    return percentage >= 0.4 || abs(velocity.x) > 300
}

func finishDismissing(velocity: CGPoint, percentage: CGFloat) -> Bool {
    return percentage >= 0.4 || abs(velocity.x) > 300
}
```

Child:

```
override weak var toViewController: UIViewController! {
didSet {
    let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissingViewController:")
    toViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
}
}

override func getPercentage(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> CGFloat {
    let translation = pan.translationInView(pan.view!)
    var percentage = translation.y / pan.view!.bounds.height

    if percentage < 0 {
        let velocity = pan.velocityInView(pan.view!)
        if velocity.y > 0 {
            pan.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: pan.view!)
            return 0
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    } else {
        return percentage
    }
}

override func onStageViewController(view: UIView) {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
}

override func offStageParentViewController(view: UIView) {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
}

override func offStageChildViewController(view: UIView) {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, view.bounds.height)
}

override func presentViewController(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = pan.locationInView((fromViewController as! MainViewController).tableView)
    let indexPath = (fromViewController as! MainViewController).tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location)

    if indexPath == nil {
        pan.state = .Failed
        return
    }
    (fromViewController as! MainViewController).instantiateAmountViewController((fromViewController as! MainViewController).defaultCurrency, indexPath: indexPath)
}

override func dismissViewController(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    toViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("DismissAmountViewControllerSegue", sender: pan)
}

override func doOnCompletion() {
    (toViewController as! AmountViewController).dismissAmountViewController()
}

override func finishDismissing(velocity: CGPoint, percentage: CGFloat) -> Bool {
    return percentage >= 0.4 && velocity.y > 0 || velocity.y > 300
}
```

The second way, I add a delegate for the parent:

```
@objc protocol InteractiveControllerTransitionDelegate {
    func getPercentage(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> CGFloat

    func onStageViewController(view: UIView)
    func offStageParentViewController(view: UIView)
    func offStageChildViewController(view: UIView)

    func presentViewController(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
    func dismissViewController(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer)

    func finishPresenting(velocity: CGPoint, percentage: CGFloat) -> Bool
    func finishDismissing(velocity: CGPoint, percentage: CGFloat) -> Bool

    optional func doOnCompletion()
    optional func doOnCancellation()
}
```

Then I just delete the "implementations" of those methods in the parent and precede any call to those methods by `delegate.` and the children implement those methods.

What is the best way practice? Or maybe both of them are wrong and there is a better one?